# Overriding paint component can only change color

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent

My code here is overriding the `paintComponent` method to color a GUI, which only has one single rectangle rect. I discover, however, that I can set the color in the function, but any other kind of formatting has no effect at all. I can't give it a border (which is my main goal), and I can't even make the color brighter. What exactly am I missing here?

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (isFirstTime) {
        area = new Rectangle(dim);
        rect.setLocation(50, 50);
        isFirstTime = false;
    }

    g2d.setColor(Color.blue.brighter().brighter());
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(100));
    g2d.fill(rect);
}
```

The overall goal here is basically to be able to highlight an object that is selected, but I cut out everything else to boil down to the basic problem.

Comment: is `rect` a `Rectangle(Dimensions)`?

Comment: @Luke it's `Rectangle(x, y, height, width)`

Comment: for the color you could look up an RGB value and say `Color color = new Color(RGBvalue)` to get the correct color and pass `color` in to `.setColor`

Comment: I vaguely remember if you do hex you can set an opacity as well which might help with highlighting

Comment: I also believe you need to pass a `Shape` into the `.fill` method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a border to a rectangle in Java using setBorder and JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457235/how-to-add-a-border-to-a-rectangle-in-java-using-setborder-and-jframe) Or maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629192/paint-method-java-rectangle-with-outline

Comment: @Abra the only way to add a border is to draw another rectangle, thus doubling the number of objects I have to keep track of? I was trying to find a way of affecting the style of one specific rectangle. Also that still doesn't seem to explain the behavior I observe that `paintcomponent` isn't affecting the style

Comment: Yes, the only way to add a border is to draw another rectangle. A [Rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) is not a [JComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html). Hence you can't set a border for a `Rectangle`. You can try to use `JPanel` instead, i.e. place smaller `JPanel`s inside a larger one. You can add "styling" to a `JPanel`. Did you look at the links in the answer from _MadProgrammer_ in the duplicate question?

Answer (score 0):

The color can be manipulated via `Color color = new Color(float R, float G, float B, float A /*RGB value and alpha value for opacity*/)` and I think you need a `Shape` instead of a `Rectangle()` to be passed into the `.fill` method. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setStroke(java.awt.Stroke) this is the documentation for Graphics2D. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html this is the documentation for Color.

Comment: Being that my goal is to highlight the rectangle, then how do I apply the style to it, if not using `.fill`? do I cast `Rectangle` as `Shape`? Also, I would prefer if I could have a method that simply highlights a given shape (such as making it brighter or bordered) instead of assigning it a constant color, because my actual code has multiple rectangles that are of different colors. Also, That really doesn't answer the original question why `paintComponent` is only capable of changing the color, unless that has something to do with using `.fill` incorrectly, which I need more explanation

Comment: The documentation you linked said `Sets the Stroke for the Graphics2D context.`. Which I set the stroke, and the result is not visibly any different. That is the issue I'm trying to solve

Comment: Changing the opacity would do the trick, maybe, if only I could do that independent of setting a constant color